# Using app-access token instead of user-access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My page is doing a API-call via the Facebook php SDK.

The call does not necessarily need a user-access token, so I can set a default access token which is the app token.

It works really nice but as every user is going to use the identical access token (from the same server ip) I wonder if there is any limitation if a certain IP address is spamming / flooding the FB Server with api calls. Is it possible for someone to use all my api-call-contingent by one single ip?

If not, is it better to use user-specific access tokens?

Comment: If you don't need user tokens, the data is presumably something that can be cached. A million anonymous users shouldn't result in a million API calls for data that's going to be identical.

Comment: It's not gonna be identical.

Comment: Then give us more details on what these calls are for.

Comment: I don't know how this helps answering my question. I do need the API calls of every user. My only question is if the Facebook PHP SDK catches the ip of the user to prevent flooding from a single ip.

Comment: it is very important to know what data exactly you want to get. would be easier to help you. and as always: the more information, the better.

Comment: @JuliusS. App tokens have a rate limit. Using them instead of user tokesn for large numbers of calls will result in being rate limited. We're trying to help you, as most API calls *require* a user token, and most of the ones that *don't* are quite limited in functionality and thus typically cacheable.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is better to use User Tokens, if you use an App Token whenever a User hits your Page, you will definitely hit API limits with a lot of Users - or even if one User hits your Page very often. You should cache results on the server if you really want to use an App Token.

Comment: I know that facebook provides a certain amount of API calls per active user per day for a single app-id and I know that this number is quite big, facebook itself says that API limiting is something that is really rare.

So actually my only question is if the Facebook PHP SDK uses the user ip to prevent flooding.

Comment: you commented that you need API calls for every user, so do them with a user token. you will definitely hit api limits with many users if you use an app token. "active user" means that he is authorized, if he is authorized, you will have a user token anyway.

Comment: Ok, then I will use the user token. Do you know for how long these tokens are valid? My app forces a login every 24 hours so that my contingent is held up. When the token is valid for at least 24 hours I can add the get-token-request in this procedure.

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: just use extended user tokens, they are valid for 60 days

Comment: Thank you for this useful link. I have 2 remaining questions concerning the extended user token:

1. Is it "ok" to safe this token on the local machine of the user?
2. Is there a "cooldown" that means a minimum time that has to pass before the user can request another user token and extend it?

Comment: 1. it is not a good idea imho, because it is valid for 60 days - and it would be pointless, because if you only use it when the user is online, you don´t need an extended one. in fact, you don´t even need to think about tokens at all, just use the js sdk. 2. not that i know of.

Comment: I got rid of the idea to save it locally, I now want to store it in a session variable and get a new token every start of the browser (it is a browser extension). What do you mean by saying I do not have to care about tokens when using the js sdk? I am using it (js sdk) for grabbing the fb login information (mostly via cookies) but I am using an api request via php sdk and therefor I need the token (I have to use the php sdk because some parameters of the call are generated by a secret algorithm). So I tried to get the access token which...

Comment: ...was created by the java sdk login by using the getJavaScriptHelper() of the facebook php sdk. The only problem left is that it gives back an object but not a string, I didnt found out how to get the access token string yet. I tried several ways I found in the documentation but none of them worked.

Comment: ok, but still: if you only need to use the token when the user is online, why even use an extended token? the standard token is valid for 2 hours, just send it to the server and make your call(s).

Comment: What would happen if a user uses the extension after 2 hours have passed? Should I check the time and get a new token after ~2 hours? Facebook doesnt even tell us for how long a token is valid, I think they say about 1-2 hours.

Comment: You said I could just "send it (the token) to the server". I can get the token via js sdk but how is the best practice to send the token to the server? Is it ok to just use a get Parameter when calling the php file?

Comment: Ok I found out that using the GET-parameter to send the token is a commno practice, I think I will now solve the whole problem @luschn Thank you very, ver much, you have helped me a lot!

Comment: Sorry for spamming so much information but using the local js SDK is not working as facebook does not permit connecting to the sdk from a browser extension. So I have to use the js SDK in a php file and somehow transfer the token to a session variable or the localStorage of the extension.